# Equations for developing a hypothetical Solar System

Tags: science-based, space, stars, solar-system, astrophysics

I am currently going down the rabbit hole of writing a story but I would like it to be set in a universe which is believable. Therefore I am trying to create a hypothetical solar system in which the world where the story takes place exists. However, as I have little to no background in astrophysics I am struggling to understand the basics.

After some research I cam across this video on how to create a star which is believable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x55nxxaWXAM&list=PLduA6tsl3gygXJbq_iQ_5h2yri4WL6zsS&index=4

The maths in this video however are not explained and when applied to existing stars...simply don't work. It begins by determining the mass of the star as anywhere between 0.6 - 1.4 solar masses -that I understand. I further understand from the video that the star would need to be of F or G classification, thus have a temperature between 5000 - 7000 K approx.

However it then goes on to calculate luminosity as Mass3 (it says 4 but it was corrected later). From further research this doesn't make any sense as luminosity would be determined by the mass-luminosity equation of L=R2⋅T4 where R is the radius and T is the temperature (though this equation seems to require the Stefan-Boltmann Constant - and sometimes not...). The video further calculates the temperature as Mass0.505…. There are more equations though the figures already break down at this point. Plus from running my own calculations I am struggling to see any meaningful relationship between a star's mass and its temperature other than bigger stars generally appear to be hotter than smaller stars.

So my question to you much more learned than I in this topic is basically:

Is there a (relatively) straight forward method of creating a hypothetical star for my solar system that is mathematically and physically feasible?

Any more info on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance to anyone would can provide some clarity"

Shane.

Comment: Hello @LearnedStudent, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. You might be [straining at a gnat](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/straining+at+a+gnat). Few if any readers are going to appreciate the level of detail you're considering. Unless your story actually needs the math as a plot point, you're about to spend a lot of time "remodeling a house" that only "needs to be painted." Do you really need this level of detail? Because it takes years to become an astrophysicist for a reason....

Comment: This question is valid for the site, because (and although) it's been asked and very well answered before on [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/175176/i-cant-seem-to-find-correct-starbuilding-equations-that-work-together-anywhere/175184#175184). In short, the luminosity-mass relation is one of proportion (you set both values at 1 for one solar mass), while the Stefan-Boltzmann law is numerical assuming you're using the right units (meters, watts, kelvins...)

Comment: "It takes years to become an astrophysicist" but only minutes to look up something similar to your star in a table, which is what the top answer recommends after describing the equations.

Comment: @parasoup - thanks for that link, just looking through it now. It certainly seems to head in exactly the right direction of what I'm trying to do. Interestingly it seems as though the poster for that question was on the same journey as me as he references the same video, and highlights the same issues I had with that video (surprisingly it did not appear as a suggested question or I would likely not have posted in the first place haha)

Comment: @JBH - I take your point that it requires a lot of detail for a seemingly small point, however I feel it makes everything else much more believable if done correctly, and helps ground the story in reality - for example it informs such things as the history, culture and lore of the world in which the story takes place and can even go as far as to dictate what may happen and why

Comment: @parasoup - Just as a follow up in regards to the link you sent. I have to agree it is very detailed, however I do feel it over complicates some of the equations (just a little bit) I had actually asked this question on the Physics forum before it was suggested to try here instead

Just for completeness and in case anyone looks at this in future I will link it below, though I am hoping someone may be able to provide a different approach, explain it in a different way or perhaps touch on something I haven't yet thought of.

Comment: HDE 226868 is fantastic at this stuff and as good as it gets when it comes to educating to the most broad degree possible. I'm compelled to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @JBH - I'm happy for you to close this one as it is almost the same as the question linked, as I mentioned it didn't appear as a suggestion before posting otherwise I would have just looked at that one instead :)